# Go back to a specific line when reading a file in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, readline, readlines

I am reading a txt file in a loop which is huge in size.
When iterating over a specific line, there are conditions and depending on which conditions are satisfied, I want to go back and start iterating over the file again from another starting line number.

For example:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for inputline in f:
        if inputline.strip() == 'abc':
            #goto line 3 and start the loop again
        print(inputline.strip())
```

Let's say the input file is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
abc
6
7
```

the output should be:

```
1
2
3
4
5
3
4
5
3
4
5.....
```

I understand that this input will eventually go into an infinite loop and will never terminate. But I still want to know how to implement this using simple readline. I cannot use the seek command as the length of each line is not uniform.

Comment: you can't go back - you would rather remeber in memory previous lines or cout chars in lines to keep positions of lines which you could use with `seek()`

Comment: "Iterating over the file again from another starting line number", when you say this is it always one particular line or does it change?

Comment: @nithin11 - the line changes depending on certain conditions.

Comment: @user2778822 so for thisinputline.strip() == 'abc' condition it goes to line 3 and for some other condition it goes to some other line. Is it like that?

Comment: @nithin11 yes, that's correct

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list to keep track of the ending position of each line (which is also the starting position of the next line) by calling the `tell` method of the file object, and then use the `seek` method to re-position the file pointer back to the position of a previous line:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    positions = []
    for inputline in f:
        position = f.tell()
        if not positions or position > positions[-1]:
            positions.append(position)
        inputline = inputline.strip()
        if inputline == 'abc':
            # the starting position of line number 3 is the ending position of line number 2
            f.seek(positions[1])
        else:
            print(inputline)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `file.seek()`:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    while f.readable():
        inputline = next(f)
        if inputline.strip() == 'abc':
            f.seek(3)
            next(f)
        else:
            print(inputline.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a *recursive* function combined with enumerate:

```
def fn(lines, index=0):
    for i, line in enumerate(lines, start=index):
    if line.strip() == 'abc':
        fn(lines, i)
    else:
        print(line)

with open(filename) as f:
    fn(f.readlines())
```